# Kubernetes pod fails with "Unable to attach or mount volumes"

Tags: kubernetes

After Kubernetes upgrade from 1.18.13 to 1.19.5 I get error bellow for some pods randomly. After some time pod fails to start(it's a simple pod, doesn't belong to deployment)

```
  Warning  FailedMount  99s   kubelet  Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[red-tmp data logs docker src red-conf], unattached volumes=[red-tmp data logs docker src red-conf]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

- On 1.18 we don't have such issue, also during upgrade K8S doesn't show any errors or incompatibility messages.
- No additional logs from any other K8S components(tried to increase verbosity level for kubelet)
- Everything is fine with disk space and other host's metrics like LA, RAM
- No network storages, only local data
- PV and PVC are created before pods and we don't change them
- Tried to use higher K8S versions but no luck

We have pretty standard setup without any special customizations:

- CNI: Flannel
- CRI: Docker
- Only one node as master and worker
- 16 cores and 32G RAM

Example of pod definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: provision
    ver: latest
  name: provision
  namespace: red
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - wait
    command:
    - provision.sh
    image: app-tests
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: provision
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/app/be
      name: src
    - mountPath: /opt/app/be/conf
      name: red-conf
    - mountPath: /opt/app/be/tmp
      name: red-tmp
    - mountPath: /var/lib/app
      name: data
    - mountPath: /var/log/app
      name: logs
    - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      name: docker
  dnsConfig:
    options:
    - name: ndots
      value: "2"
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: false
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /opt/agent/projects/app-backend
      type: Directory
    name: src
  - name: red-conf
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: conf
  - name: red-tmp
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: tmp
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: data
  - name: logs
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: logs
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
      type: Socket
    name: docker
```

PV

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: red-conf
  labels:
    namespace: red
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /var/lib/docker/k8s/red-conf
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: red-conf
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

PVC

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: conf
  namespace: red
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: red-conf
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: red-conf
```

`tmp data logs` pv have the same setup as `conf` beside path. They have separate folders:

```
/var/lib/docker/k8s/red-tmp
/var/lib/docker/k8s/red-data
/var/lib/docker/k8s/red-logs
```

Currently I don't have any clues how to diagnose the issue :(

Would be glad to get advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: - Since PVC/PV are hostPath & error is at mounting state .. you can start investigation from checking `/var/log/messages` of the worker node where this pod is scheduled.. I am guessing you might see some mount/unmount related errors ...

Comment: Thanks for reply @confusedgenius. I've already tried to check but nothing found :(

Comment: @RomanBzh Welcome to Stack Overflow! If any of the answers below has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark or just [upvote it if was useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to start troubleshooting by reviewing the [VolumeAttachment](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/rest_api/storage_apis/volumeattachment-storage-k8s-io-v1.html) events against what node has tied the PV, perhaps your volume is still linked to a node that was in evicted condition and was replaced by a new one.

You can use this command to check your PV name and status:

```
kubectl get pv
```

And then, to review what node has the correct volumeattachment, you can use the following command:

```
kubectl get volumeattachment
```

Once you get the name of your PV and at what node it is attached, then you will be able to see if the PV is tied to the correct node or if maybe it is tied to a previous node that is not working or was removed. The node gets evicted and scheduled into a new available node from the pool; to know what nodes are ready and running, you can use this command:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

If you detect that your PV is tied to the node that no longer exists, you will need to delete the VolumeAttachment with the following command:

```
kubectl delete volumeattachment [csi-volumeattachment_name]
```

If you need to review a detailed guide for this troubleshooting, you can follow [this link](https://veducate.co.uk/kubelet-unable-attach-volumes/).

Comment: Thanks for reply Leo. We start fresh one node K8S in CI on a new EC2 instance hence we don't have any leftovers or traces of previous runs/nodes.

Answer (score 0):

you must be using local volumes. Follow the below link to understand how to create storage class, pv's and pvc when you use local volumes.

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I intentionally use HostPath volumes here since it's one node installation, also It's a dev environment.